# Dynamic image load on page load in forms Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

i have a question regarding dynamic reloading of images that i want to display to the user.

To put you in context, I have 2 tables, one ‘PEOPLE_INFO’ containing infos about people (full_name, photo_blob, …) , and the other PEOPLE_QUOTE' contains Quotes and messages that these people submit. So the two tables are linked by a FK in the latter.

Now what I want to do is to create a form where a user/admin can enter and add/update the quotes of these people. The form is based on the PEOPLE_QUOTE table, and i want to add an image display where we can show the photo that the person has in the PEOPLE_INFO table.

---

What i was planing to do is to have a dynamic action lunch on page load, that will set the value of the display image to the blob returned by an sql statement, and then refresh that display image item.

```
SELECT photo_blob FROM people_info WHERE people_id = :P1_PEOPLE_ID
```

But the image doesn't change and i can't seem to wrap my had around why this happens.

---

[Dynamic Action structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHNa8.png)

APEX Version: 20.2.0.00.20 #sql #user-interface #general

Comment: what set value does?

Comment: Why a dynamic action ? This should just be a before rendering page process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a N:1 relationship between PEOPLE_QUOTE and PEOPLE_INFO you can create a form on a select that includes a join between PEOPLE_QUOTE and PEOPLE_INFO. That way your image can just be stored in a page item. No need for a dynamic action.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate your form source that using sql, as the following:

```
select PEOPLE_QUOTE.*, PEOPLE_INFO.photo_blob 
from PEOPLE_QUOTE , PEOPLE_INFO
where PEOPLE_INFO.people_id = PEOPLE_QUOTE.people_id and
 PEOPLE_QUOTE = :P_ID;
```

I suppose the people_id column is the FK in the two tables. and P_ID is the page item which is recive the value of primary key from PEOPLE_QUOTE table.